# Automating constantly changing json parse queries for constantly changing structures

Tags: python, c, json

I have an external c dll I call using python ctypes. The structures in my dll change often and dramatically, meaning I need to rewrite my ctypes structures in python to match.

On top of this I also have the requirement to read data in from a json file that also changes often.

Basically I'm constantly shuffling and renaming python ctypes classes and json queries. None of the parameters or names match up, and so I'm hoping I can automate this some how. My question is, if you had to do this what would the be a toolset or library you would recommend?